# Extremely slow MySQL performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-schema

I have a table with about 500K jobs, each job has a unique ID which is used as primary key and a status that is used to indicate whether the job is pending, complete or failed. The status is an integer that is not key.

My problem is that a simple query where I try to select jobs based on the status takes too much time, more than 10 minutes. There are about 46 threads connected in the DB and I also did a restart but it didn't help the performance.

I pasted the table schema and the query I try to run here:
http://pastie.org/10416054

Is there any way to find what's the bottleneck and optimize the table so it doesn't take that long?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After hours I would rifle off the following command:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_qry_status ON queries(status);
```

As your query is doing a tablescan, employing no index whatsoever.

See the Manual page on [Create Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

A visual of the after, table-wise (not performance-wise):

```
create table queries
(   id bigint auto_increment primary key,
    status int null
    -- partial definition
);
insert queries (status) values (7),(2),(1),(4),(1),(5),(9),(11);

CREATE INDEX idx_qry_status ON queries(status);
show indexes from queries;
+---------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| queries |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | id          | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| queries |          1 | idx_qry_status |            1 | status      | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying I'm making a backup and I'm trying it now.

Comment: Works great, query time went down from 11 minutes to less than 1 sec. I'm reading now an interesting article on MySQL indexes that explains a lot https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/2013/08/27/mysql-indexing-basics/